# SQLite - Increase speed of insertion

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

I have a method which reads data from file line by line and takes value between coma, then puts this value into INSERT query. Data in file saved in this way:

```
–,08:10,–,20:20,08:15,08:16,20:26,20:27,08:20,08:21,20:31,20:32,08:30,08:31,20:40,20:41,08:37,08:38,20:46
20:47,08:48,08:50,20:56,20:57,09:00,09:01,21:07,21:08
08:53,–,17:43,09:01,09:03,09:13,09:15,18:02,18:04,–,–,09:19,09:25
```

Here is actual my code:

```
    public void insertTime(SQLiteDatabase database, String table) throws FileNotFoundException {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line;

        try {
            int j = 0;
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open("time.txt")));
            database.beginTransaction();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                j++;

                String query = "INSERT INTO "+table+""+j+" (arrival, departure) VALUES (?,?)";
                SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(query);
                // use comma as separator
                String[] time = line.split(",");


                for(int i = 1; i < time.length; i+=2) {

                    statement.bindString(1,time[i-1]);//arrival
                    statement.bindString(2,time[i]);//departure
                    statement.executeInsert();
                    statement.clearBindings();
                }

            }
                database.setTransactionSuccessful();
                database.endTransaction();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that data insert very slow, despite I use `SQLiteStatement` and `transactions`. For example, when I insert 69000 rows it takes about 65,929 seconds.

What have I to change in my code to improve speed of insertion ?

**UPDATE**

OK, I have simplified my code, I got rid of BufferedReader and now it looks like this

```
public void insertTime(SQLiteDatabase database) throws FileNotFoundException {
        database.beginTransaction();
        int r = 0;
        while (r < 122) {
            r++;
            String query = "INSERT INTO table_1 (arrival, departure) VALUES (?,?)";
            SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(query);

            for(int i = 1; i < 1100; i++) {
                statement.bindString(1,i+"");//arrival
                statement.bindString(2,i+"");//departure
                statement.executeInsert();
                statement.clearBindings();
            }
        }

        database.setTransactionSuccessful();
        database.endTransaction();
}
```

But it still so long inserts data, more than 2 min. Do you have any ideas how to increase speed of my second example ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Improve INSERT-per-second performance of SQLite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/improve-insert-per-second-performance-of-sqlite)

Comment: there all code wrote on C how can it help me if I use java ?

Comment: sqlite is sqlite everywhere. the only thing that is C in that post is how to execute an sqlite command. The sql statements are the same in any medium.

Comment: Yes, but I did almost all like said there. I used transactions and prepared statement, but speed still slow.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/improve-insert-per-second-performance-of-sqlite) is a very very detailed post on every method of increasing SQL insertion speed.

Answer (score 0):

Move `beginTransaction()` and `setTransactionSuccessful()` outside of `while` loop and it will be way faster.

Comment: I did like you said but speed still the same - about 65 seconds

Comment: Can you share your changes?

Comment: Hmm. Difficult to say then. Try to add some code collecting execution time of compileStatement() and executeInsert() methods to see what the bottleneck is. Once you know it, there will be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

A new transaction is started for each item in the `while()` loop.
It might go a bit faster if you only have 1 transaction to do all your insertions.

Also, when your data is corrupt and `String.split` doesn't give you at least 2 items, then your transaction will not be ended properly due to an `Exception` being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you insert a row in a table with indexes, the indexes have to be adjusted. That operation can be costly. Indexes are kept as b-trees and if you hit the rebalance point, you're bound to have a slowdown. One thing you can do to test this is to remove your indexes. You could also drop the indexes, insert, then re-create the indexes.

Comment: I also think to make PRAGMA synchronous=OFF. But, where should I put this command in my code ?

Comment: @gigs In theory, anywhere after your connection. But I'd say just before your transaction and turn it ON again right after you end your transaction if you keep using that connection.

Comment: I added "database.execSQL("PRAGMA synchronous=OFF")" before transaction and "database.execSQL("PRAGMA synchronous=NORMAL")" after transaction. But it gives me an error: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Safety level may not be changed inside a transaction (code 1): , while compiling: PRAGMA synchronous=OFF

Comment: @gigs I haven't worked with Android and SQLite together. Try to move your PRAGMA just after your connection as a test.

Answer (score 0):

For those using JDBC (Java): to be sure, **do you first set the autoCommit to FALSE**?

I guess so, because you work with explicit transactions.

The performace gain I got by explicitly setting the autocommit off **was over 1000 times**!

So:

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
String urlInput = "jdbc:sqlite:" + databaseFile;
databaseConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(urlInput);
databaseConnection.setAutoCommit( false);
```

And:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " ( type, bi, ci, fvi, tvi, content_type) VALUES ('V',?,?,?,?,'rtf')";
PreparedStatement psi = databaseConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
for( Item item :  items) {
    psi.setInt(1, item.property1);
    // ....
    count = psi.executeUpdate();
}
databaseConnection.commit();
databaseConnection.setAutoCommit( true);
```

So, when somebody forgets this, this may have a huge effect.